# take screenshot of a website and return taken screenshot for download in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

i want to take a screenshot from a website and return taken screenshot as https for download. I am using Html2Image lib. i am tring this code:

```
def certification1(request, *args, **kwargs):
hti = Html2Image()
image = hti.screenshot(url='https://www.python.org', save_as='screenshot.png')
response = HttpResponse(image, content_type='png')
return response
```

but it return url of saved image. like this
how can i return taken image for download?

Comment: is this returning url of the image stored locally or returning the same url you have provided ? Can you post some details on the response

Comment: @Santosh Balaji . it returning url of the image stored locally. and i can see the taken screenshot in this url